# Why the IO.Writer doesn't fill the receiver?

Tags: go

I'm trying to test a template generation tool. In order to do this I was thinking that the easiest way to capture the template execution output is to use a io writer and provide it during testing. The issue is that for some reasons the receiver is not "updated" with the template output. Hopefully the code below explains better the issue I'm facing.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "text/template"

type Company struct{
    Name string
} 

type Companies []Company

func main() {
    s := new(stringer)

    v := Companies{Company{Name:"Sony"}}
    tmp :=  template.Must(template.New("main").Parse(src))
    if err := tmp.Execute(s, v); err !=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    if *s != "this is the header template"{
        fmt.Println("expected: \"this is the header template\" received: ", *s) 
    }else{
      fmt.Println("s is %v", *s)
    }
}

type stringer string
func (s *stringer)Write(b []byte)(int, error){
    *s = stringer(b)
    return len(b), nil
}

var src = `
 this is the header template
    {{range .}}

    {{.Name}}

    {{end}}
`
```

http://play.golang.org/p/y4zWgyd5G1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `stringer` type is just an "alias" to `*string` type. `string` in Go is immutable. You shouldn't use a `string` or a pointer to a `string` to build the the output of a template, because you can't modify a `string`, you can only create a new (and throw away the old one).

[`template.Execute()`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) expects an [`io.Writer`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer). The `Write()` method of the output might be called multiple times, and your `stringer.Write()` method always throws away data written to it earlier. You could fix it by always concatenating the new data to the old like this:

```
*s = *s + stringer(b)
```

But this solution is terribly inefficient (it generates new `string`s and throws away old ones).

A much better and ready-to-use alternative is [`bytes.Buffer`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer). You can create a byte buffer which implements the `Writer` interface like this:

```
bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
```

You don't need to create your own `stringer` type. Try your modified program on [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/GzNb9CG_er).

Comment: I'm not sure I get the issue with io.Writer. Didn't I provide an io.Writer? Otherwise it won't compile isn't it ?

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat Edited the answer. Your `stringer.Writer()` method might be called multiple times and your implementation always throws away data written to it earlier.

Comment: Got it ... I didn't know it calls it several times, thus the whole misunderstanding. I'm wondering if I should use a buffer too if I want to write the output to a file. Initially I thought I could give it just an *os.File( http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write) argument but I guess it's not the case as it would truncate the file content just like it did with my receiver, right ?

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat No, passing a `File` to `Execute()` is perfectly fine. It doesn't matter how many times `File.Write()` is called, because the implementation writes out the bytes passed to it, it will not be lost.